# Coldfusion 10 - Element [n] is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I recently upgraded a system from CF8 to CF10 and have one bug that I'm having problems tracking down.  It has to do with a remote API call that gets a JSON string back and that string then gets converted to a query object.  That's where I'm coming across the error:

Element [n] is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array. The problem is in the function that converts the string to a query.

```
<cffunction name="CFjsonToQuery" access="public" returntype="query" output="no">
  <cfargument name="cfData" required="yes" type="struct"/>
  <cfset var LOCAL = {}/>
    <cfset LOCAL.tmpQry = QueryNew( ArrayToList(ARGUMENTS.cfData.Data.COLUMNS) ) />
       <cfloop index = "i" from = "1" to = "#ArrayLen(ARGUMENTS.cfData.Data.DATA)#">
         <cfset LOCAL.Row = QueryAddRow(LOCAL.tmpQry) />
           <cfloop index="k" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(ARGUMENTS.cfData.Data.DATA[i])#">
             <cfset LOCAL.colName = ARGUMENTS.cfData.Data.COLUMNS[K]/>
             <cfset QuerySetCell(LOCAL.tmpQry,LOCAL.colName,ARGUMENTS.cfData.Data.DATA[i][k],LOCAL.Row)/>
           </cfloop>    
       </cfloop>
  <cfreturn LOCAL.tmpQry/>
</cffunction>
```

Anywhere the JSON returns 'null' (i.e. "...","19107-3609",null,null,null,"...") the error is thrown.  I've tried using isNull to check if it's null in the cfloop:

```
<cfif isNull(ARGUMENTS.cfData.Data.DATA[i][k])>
   <cfset ARGUMENTS.cfData.Data.DATA[i][k] = 'I AM NULL'/>
</cfif>
```

EDIT - here's a simplified example - the issue is the way the newer deserializeJson() works I believe:

```
<cfset jstr = '{"SUCCESS":true,"ERRORS":[],"DATA":{"COLUMNS":["ID","FNAME","LNAME"],"DATA":[[390132,"steve",null]]}}'/>
<cfset cfData = deserializeJson(jstr) />
  <cfloop index = "i" from = "1" to = "#ArrayLen(cfData.Data.DATA)#">
    <cfset Row = QueryAddRow(tmpQry) />
      <cfloop index="k" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(cfData.Data.DATA[i])#">
        <cfset colName = cfData.Data.COLUMNS[K]/>
        <cfset QuerySetCell(tmpQry,colName,cfData.Data.DATA[i][k],Row)/>
      </cfloop>
  </cfloop>
```

I've tried all sorts of tests for empty string, isNull etc. and I'm still not sure how to get the query object built if deserializejson returns:

```
[undefined array element] Element 3 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array.
```

This does seem to work:

```
<cfset cfData = deserializeJson(returnData,'FALSE') />
<cfset qryData = cfData.data />
```

This lets me then use qryData as if it were a normal cfquery.

Comment: Try checking for an empty string.

Comment: I cannot recall which version of CF they fixed it in, but CF used to deserialise `NULL` as `"NULL"` (ie: as a string with the value null); it's certainly doing that in CF9.0.1. If it's fixed in CF10, you might be getting a change in behaviour there? Also: you're not local-scoping your array counters, which could cause you grief if you are reusing the object. This *could* be related if other functions use `i` or `k`, or if you're running this function simultaneously on the same object in more than one thread.

Comment: They are locally scoped in the actual function - I just deleted some of that so it was less of a wall of text.  I just added a simple string with 3 values that shows the error.  I've seen blog posts by you, Ben N. and others that discuss this but not an example that (so far) applies to the problem I'm having.

Comment: Put a try/catch around the line that's erroring, and dump out all the participating variables. That should clarify what's going on.

Comment: What I've done for now is add 'FALSE' to the deserializeJSON strictMapping flag and that seems to automatically create a query object?  I'll admit though this is getting into the underpinnings of CF10 and I could be wrong on that.  I'll update my code above for visual clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done for now is add 'FALSE' to the deserializeJSON strictMapping flag and that seems to automatically create a query object? I'll admit though this is getting into the underpinnings of CF10 and I could be wrong on that. I'll update my code above for visual clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a check if the element is undefined using the CF Function [ArrayIsDefined(array, elementIndex)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ed3.html)